# Docker イメージをbuildできない問題について

Tags: docker

下記の記事を参考にdockerを利用しておりました。

[GCPとDockerでKaggle用計算環境構築 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/lain21/items/a33a39d465cd08b662f1)

先日まで問題なく使えていたのですが、新しいイメージをbuildしようとすると下記エラーが
でるようになりました。原因と対策を教えていただけますでしょうか。
お忙しい中、恐縮ですが、お願いします。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     sudo git wget cmake nano vim gcc g++ build-essential ca-certificates software-properties-common     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 3a0c0cb0cba1
/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     sudo git wget cmake nano vim gcc g++ build-essential ca-certificates software-properties-common     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-cudnn7-runtime-centos7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo git wget cmake nano vim gcc g++ build-essential ca-certificates software-properties-common \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install python
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y python3.6 \
&& wget -O ./get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py \
&& python3.6 ./get-pip.py \
&& ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3 \
&& ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python

# install common python packages
ADD ./requirements.txt /tmp
RUN pip install pip setuptools -U && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.6.0
RUN pip install keras==2.1.5

# set working directory
WORKDIR /root/user

# config and clean up
RUN ldconfig \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: `Dockerfile`や利用しているDockerイメージの情報があると回答の参考になるかと思います。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。イメージはNGCのCUDA9.0です。（古いtensorflowを使いたいためです）

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get`コマンドはDebian/Ubuntu系のOSで使用するコマンドですが、Dockerfileで指定されているのはCentOSになっているので「(apt-get)コマンドが見つからない」となっています。

元々使用できていたのであれば恐らくOSイメージの指定が間違っているのだと思うので、こちらをよく確認してみてください。
仮にもしCentOSを使うつもりであるなら、パッケージのインストールは`yum`コマンドを使用する必要があります。

Comment: ubuntuに変えてみた所うまく行きました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。